# Inline editing DataTable in Lightning Design

Tags: lightning, datatable

I'm currently working on a DataTables in Lightning Design. I basically want to implement the Inline editing feature. I found it bit hard to implement this with real data within Apex:repeat. Can someone please help to share a sample code with me?

Comment: Is this Lightning or Visualforce? Or Lightning Design in Visualforce?

Comment: Its Lightning Design in VisualForce

Answer (score -2):

See this link: [Componente Library-Datatabel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation)

Look for "Column Properties" in this page and editable property. Set this property to true.

Or see this sample : [enter link description here](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/12/08/lightning-data-table-inline-editing/)

You can use lightning components in your visualpage, check this.:
[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm?search_text=visual)

for hardcode sample that do you want,  many code is necessary to make this and many javascript.

Comment: While the question is confusing, note that in comments the asker specifies that they are using Lightning Design in Visualforce, *not* Lightning Components.

Comment: ok, but you can use de lightning components in your visual page too: [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm?search_text=visual), but have a one sample in site that i put in my answer now.